# loop with matrix values

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, matrix

i have a group of values and i need a specific output:

i have in table these values:

```
           id | value
           1  |  1/4
           2  |  5/1
           3  |  4/1
           4  |  6/1
           5  |  2/1
           6  |  3/1
```

**What i'm trying to do:**

```
    A | B   | C   | D   | 
A | 1 | 1/4 | 5/1 | 4/1 | 
B |   | 1   | 6/1 | 2/1 |
C |   |     |  1  | 3/1 |
D |   |     |     | 1   |
```

I only have 6 values, and i pretend an output with 10 values

output intended:

```
$matrix[0][0] = 1/1;
$matrix[0][1] = 1/4;
$matrix[0][2] = 5/1;
$matrix[0][3] = 4/1;

$matrix[1][1] = 1/1;
$matrix[1][2] = 6/1;
$matrix[1][3] = 2/1;

$matrix[2][2] = 1/1;
$matrix[2][3] = 3/1;

$matrix[3][3] = 1/1;
```

I am trying something like this but without successful:

```
while ($sql -> fetch()) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < (//something); $i++) {
            for ($x = 0; $x < (//something); $x++) {
            $matrix[$i][$i+1] = $result;
            }
        }
    }
```

any idea? thanks

Comment: question updated. This is an AHP algorithm.

Comment: @loops i am new to ahp algorithm. can you provide more data on how a select of 4 rows will look like and a select on 5 rows will look like

Comment: @Babu the question is updated to 4 values (4*4 matrix)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to implement this in php. the below is a java code for your logic.

```
Integer[] singleDim = new Integer[] {2,3, 2};
int matrixSiz = 3;      //this value has to be set manually. 
                    //i didnt get time to find the logic for this 

Integer[][] twoDim = new Integer[matrixSiz][matrixSiz];
int counter = 0;      //this iterates through singleDim array
//logic being done for convesion
for (int i = 0; i < matrixSiz; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < matrixSiz; j++) {
        if (i==j) {
            twoDim[i][j]=1;  //setting the diagonal as 1
        }else if (j>i){     // important condition to find the upper part of the matrix
            twoDim[i][j]=singleDim[counter++];
        }
    }
}
//printing it.
for (int i = 0; i < matrixSiz; i++) {
    System.out.println();        //new line
    for (int j = 0; j < matrixSiz; j++) {
        if(twoDim[i][j]==null)
            System.out.print("\t");
        else 
            System.out.print("\t"+twoDim[i][j]);
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
1   2   3
    1   2
        1
```

The above logic should work by changing `singleDim` and `matrixSiz` for any data.